# Pulsing one-way current

Tags: voltage, ac, dc

In EveryCircuit, they have three different voltage sources, one is DC (left), one is AC (middle), and then one is just pulsing (right) --

[image]

Is there a formal name for the 'pulsing one-way-current'? Is this used at all in practical applications, or only really in simulators? I was only aware of AC and DC until using these simulations.

Comment: `pulse train` .... sometimes called `clock signal`

Comment: Unipolar or bipolar defines pulse options. Probably logic level clock (unipolar)  for CD4000 series logic

Comment: Also, it's not called "one-way". It's called unipolar which means it goes from zero to positive, or much less frequently zero to negative. As opposed to bipolar which goes both positive and negative.